# Corona body removing itself from the physic world

Tags: lua, box2d, coronasdk

I currently using the game template created by Corona SDK, to develop my game, what i trying to do is something very simple, i want the crate to stay where it was spawned, and only move after the crate is tapped. To achieve that I tried to remove the `gravityScale` of the crate. This is what i have done:

```
local function crateTap( event )
    print( "gravityScale : " .. event.target.gravityScale)
    event.target.gravityScale = 1
    print( "gravityScale : " .. event.target.gravityScale)
end

local crate = display.newImageRect( "crate.png", 45, 45 )
crate.x, crate.y = 160, 20
crate.rotation = 15

-- add physics to the crate
physics.addBody( crate, { density=1.0, friction=0.3, bounce=0.3 } )
crate.gravityScale = 0

crate:addEventListener( "tap", crateTap )
```

The application loads ok, and if i click really fast on the crate, like in the first second on the screen, the crate will fall off, but if i wait a little and click, nothing will happen. And i have no idea why.

Here's the complete level1.lua file http://pastebin.com/yjxmGqw5

Thanks

Comment: What is the output produced as a result of the two print statements? I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: gravityScale: 0, gravityScale: 1.

Answer (score 0):

Then the issue is elsewhere in your code. There is nothing wrong with the code as shown. Gravity scale can be changed at any time, and takes effect as soon as the event handler returns. The fact that it works early on shows this. That it then stops working indicates that something else happens somewhere after a second of play, like perhaps the physics engine gets paused by another event, or something in an enterFrame event handler.